# How to debug ManualReset and AutoReset event?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I there any feature in Visual Studio that let me check how many AutoReset/ManualReset events are waiting at certain point in the code when I stop for a break  point? I am debugging a large application and it is getting messy to keep things in my mind.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **Parallel Stacks** debugger window.  It won't specifically isolate reset events, but it's the fastest way I can think of to see where each waiting thread is blocked.  It does a decent job of collapsing multiple threads together where they have identical call stack sections.

[image: Parallel Stacks in Action]

Comment: Thanks.. Will try this thing out.

Comment: You're going to love it if you debug a lot of multi-threaded applications :).